# Results in file not found error GZIP HASH-LIB

Tags: python-3.x, ipython, gzip, mnist, hashlib

can anyone help me understand why this is resulting in a file not found error, trying to fetch the datasets from the mnist dataset to follow along with someone else doing the same thing, on their end this exact code works fine.

```
def fetch(url):
  import requests, gzip, os, hashlib, numpy
  fp = os.path.join("/tmp", hashlib.md5(url.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest())
  if not os.path.isfile(fp):
    with open(fp, "rb") as f:
      dat = f.read()
  else:
    with open(fp, "wb") as f:
      dat = requests.get(url).content
      f.write(dat)
  return numpy.frombuffer(gzip.decompress(dat), dtype=np.uint8).copy()
X_train = fetch("http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz")[0x10:].reshape((-1, 28, 28))
Y_train = fetch("http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/train-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz")[8:]
X_test = fetch("http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/t10k-images-idx3-ubyte.gz")[0x10:].reshape((-1, 28, 28))
Y_test = fetch("http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/t10k-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz")[8:]


<ipython-input-2-11c57312a7ae> in fetch(url)
      6   print(fp)
      7   if not os.path.isfile(fp):
----> 8     with open(fp, "rb") as f:
      9       dat = f.read()
     10   else:

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/23278f029ff68f1e993776e500ce06b9'
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem. So i looked up some of the documentation for the os module and it said this "os.path.isfile(path) Return True if path is an existing regular file..." so I really don't know how this worked for hotz but it seemed to not give me an error when I added a folder "/tmp" in my project directory and changed the "if not os.path.isfile(fp):" to "if os.path.isfile(fp):". like I said not sure exactly why this would work but my thinking is that the .isfile() method should return false if there is no file and when you first call the fetch function there shouldnt be a "/tmp/hexnumberblah" file so you want the program to do what is under the else statement(request the file from the url).

Comment: also I just went over to jupyter notebook and if you run it from there you don't have to change anything

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow & thanks for your answer! I suggest adding backticks `` ` `` around all Python code statements and function names. That will make your answer more readable. On the same token, I suggest to add 2 consecutive newlines to separate paragraphs.